# Usar javascript dentro de arquivo EJS para mostrar informações de um array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, ejs

Estou tentando mostrar dentro de um arquivo EJS/html os valores de um array que são enviados do servidor, mas não estou conseguindo.
Sei que para mostrar o valor de uma variável dentro de um arquivo EJS tudo que eu preciso fazer é colocar o nome da variável dentro das tags `<=% %>`, como por exemplo: `<%= helloWord %>`, mas agora estou tentando executar um laço `for` dentro desta tag para mostrar os dados de um array, mas não está funcionando. Alguém sabe como fazer isso funcionar? Segue abaixo código da página:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Página Inicial</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3><%= artwork %></h3>
    <center>
      <img src="images/IMG01.jpg" alt="Imagem da Obra de Arte 1" title="Obra de Arte 1"></br>
    </center>

    <div class="container">
      <p id="message">
        <%=  
          for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            log[i];
          }

        %>
      </p>


      <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="inputQuestion" placeholder="Pergunte-me" required />
        <button>Enviar</button>
      </form>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para processamento você usa <% %>, e para imprimir você usa <%= %>.

Então vai ficar assim:

```
<% for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { %>
  <%= log[i] %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Entendi. Só mais uma coisa, se eu quisesse que o valor de `i` dentro do `for` fosse até o tamanho da array, como eu deveria colocar então?

Comment: seria como em javascript mesmo, "for(let i = 0; i < log.length; i++)"